# Bundle is installed, yet `-bash: bundle: command not found` when using any bundle command in app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm setting up a new Mac and trying to get dev environemnt set up. Using Homebrew & RVM as package managers. I have bundler installed when i run `bundler -v` from root it get `Bundler version 1.13.6` no problem.

However I've just cloned one of my app projects locally and when in that app's directory `bundler` returns `command not found`. Surley I shouldn't need to install Bundler when in each directory?!? Is this some user permisisons issue? Can you help me understand this situation and why bundler doesn't work in the newly pulled app directory? Ultimately I'm just trying to bundle install the gemfile for this newly cloned application.

gem environment

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/usr/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/usr/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
     - /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin
     - /Users/jusr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /Users/usr/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

echo $PATH

```
/Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/Users/usr/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

which gem

```
/Users/usr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/gem
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue the following command:

```
rmv use 2.2.2
```

Comment: `ruby -v` returns
`ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin16]`
so already it's already using 2.2.2, and `rvm use 2.2.2` returns
`Using /Users/jbkimac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2`
So that's not the solution Hossam I'm afraid!